# Is there an API available to query for all in progress bulk api jobs?

Tags: bulk-api

I need to programmatically list all the currently in progress bulk api jobs. I don't see any API methods available to do this.

The goal here is to be able to wait till there are no in progress bulk api jobs and then kick off a new one.

This is not a duplicate. I don't really care if I use APEX or the bulk api or what I use, but I need to be able to get a list of all jobs or ideally of all in progress jobs. Once I have the job ID I can get all the info I need. What I don't know how to do is get a list of all bulk api jobs.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I don't really care if I use APEX or the bulk api or what I use, but I need to be able to get a list of all jobs or ideally of all in progress jobs. Once I have the job ID I can get all the info I need. What I don't know how to do is get a list of all bulk api jobs.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the help. The issue is that the Bulk API (or any API that I have found) does not have a method to get a list of bulk jobs (like the list on the Bulk Data Load Jobs page in Setup). It has methods to create jobs, abort jobs, query for a specific job by ID.

Comment: Which is why I marked it as duplicate, the answer is the same (currently) the object is not exposed. Added as an answer here so you can accept if you feel it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Adrian's answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139850/how-do-we-refer-bulk-data-load-jobs-in-apex/139875#139875):

> The object you seek is **AsyncApiJob**, but it can't be queried. Vote for
>   this [Idea: Ability to query AsyncApiJob from Apex.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l30hAAA)