# Report on Monitor bulk data load jobs

Tags: custom-reports, monitoring

Can someone help me to create report on Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs? It is not available via configuration it seems. So is it possible via code and how?

Thanks,
Sanjana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such out of box functionality available right now. It is in [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ibe8AAA) stage, where you can upvote this Idea.

For custom solution please refer to this [SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139850/how-do-we-refer-bulk-data-load-jobs-in-apex/139875#139875) and check Adrian's answer.

Comment: Thanks Saroj for the help. But is it possible to atlease extract the data load jobs data?